# Reading data from downloaded .txt file downloaded multiple times in Android app

Tags: android, file

I'm developing an app in which I'm sending a .txt file from one end by attaching it with gmail. Everytime this file is sent, its name is data.txt. When this file is downloaded at the other end, on the first download its name is the same, i.e. data.txt. However, when another file is sent with the same name, the name of the file at the receiveing end becomes data-1.txt, data-2.txt etc. And because of this, I'm not able to read the proper file. Please could someone give me some suggestions to solve this problem? The sending and receiving code is given below: SEND

```
  bSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String fileName = "data";
            String toWrite = enterText.getText().toString();
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                Log.v("path", path);
                File myFile = new File("" + path + "/" + fileName + ".txt");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append(toWrite);
                Log.v("file written", toWrite);
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
                Uri u1 = null;
                u1 = Uri.fromFile(myFile);

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "MPPT Configuration Data");
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u1);
                sendIntent.setType("text/html");
                startActivity(sendIntent);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
```

READ:

```
  bRead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String fileName = "data";
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String aDataRow = "";
            String aBuffer = "";
            try {

                    File myFile = new File("/storage/sdcard0/download/" + fileName + ".txt");
                    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                    BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(fIn));
                    while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
                    }
                    myReader.close();
                    Log.v("read data", "" + aBuffer);
                    tvData.setText(aBuffer);



            }catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Delete the older one before downloading new one.

Comment: On the receiving side you should just list the files in the download directory and determine the one with the highest number.

Comment: `receiving code is given below`. Wrong. The users mail program is receiving it. Your code is not receiving at all. Your code tries to read a file.

Comment: @VikramSingh The file is downloaded separately by the user. It is not done from my app.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry, I meant the code where data from the file is read.

Comment: Before writing data.txt, first check if its already there, if it is delete it and create new. or if you need the data of data.txt as well then first check if data.txt is there and read its data to a variable and the delete the file and create data.txt again and concatinate your new data to the old one you read before deleting.

Comment: Delete data.txt after you read it is a possibility.

Comment: @Semicolon I don't think that's gonna work. We're dealing with 2 different phones here. I cant check if the file is present at the receiving end, from the sending end.

Comment: @Prat you don't have to check at receiving end. Problem lies in creating a file on sending phone. you need to check that at sending end. And I think after downloading the file at receiving end you have to delete it or move it to the other location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution. I can link the file manager (external app) from where the user can pick out whichever file he wants to be read.
Thanks @greenapps fir the idea of displaying a list of files.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the file by using regex ,then process the file by following way:

1.if only one file found,read it;

2.if more than one file found, compare and read the file which last number is biggest

but this solution still has one problem,if has file data.txt and data-3.txt ,the file we want to read may become data-2.txt,but what we really read is data-3.txt.

Or,maybe you can get the file you want by judging file established time.